# Silverlight DataGrid databinding problem

Tags: silverlight

Say I have a table name is MyData, the I have a column have the same name MyData. so the table looks like

```
MyData(ID, MyData, Col3, ....)
```

Using EF and Ria Service to get data from DB and bind data to a datagrid like:

```
<data:DataGridTextColumn Header="ID"  Binding="{Binding ID}" />
<data:DataGridTextColumn Header="MyData"  Binding="{Binding MyData}" />
<data:DataGridTextColumn Header="Col3"  Binding="{Binding Col3}" />  
...
```

then run it, I can get all data displayed for all other columns except MyData column. Nothing displayed for Mydata.

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: What is MyData?  Is it an object with properties or a collection of other objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have an object called MyData and then a property with exactly that name, try change the name of your table and see if it works...

Comment: Thanks, guys.  Figured out reason. EF generated Entity MyData and change the property name MyData1, not MyData. So when binding data, should use Mydata1, not MyData.